# make zsh run a command when no command is entered

Tags: terminal, zsh

Imagine I am typing at my terminal prompt, but actually decide not to type anything. Instead I just press enter.

Is there a way I can make zsh run a command now?

I want to potentially make this command variable, e.g. repeat the last command, or if the last command was `z` then pressing enter on the blank prompt should run `echo $PWD`.

How can I do this?

Comment: you might find some options with https://superuser.com/a/625663/513541, although I'd point out that "an empty command" is vastly different than the non-empty command "`z`". I, myself, struck out on the `TRAPDEBUG()` route -- an empty command seems not to trigger it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I meant that if I run `z` it takes me to a directory, and then pressing enter (on the now blank command line, re-drawn prompt) it should run my specified `echo $PWD`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `preexec` and `precmd` hooks:

```
preexec(){ cmd=$1; }
precmd(){ if [ "$cmd" ]; then lcmd=$cmd; cmd=; else; echo "<no command> last was <$lcmd>"; fi; }

zsh$ :
zsh$
<no command> last was <:>
zsh$ pwd
/home2/ahq
```

You should read the whole thing in the `Hook Functions` subsection in the `zshmisc(1)` manpage, especially the part about the arguments which are passed to `preexec`.

Also, instead of defining the hook functions directly, you can use [`add-zsh-hook`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-hook-function-utility):

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook -Uz precmd my_precmd
```